# How to set granular repo scopes for GitHub App?

Tags: github, github-api

I am building a webservice that can connect to a users GitHub repository. For this I created and configured a GitHub app. In the settings of the GitHub app I can see an installation button:

[image]

After clicking on install, I get forwarded to the installation link:

`https://github.com/apps/test-app/installations/new/permissions?target_id=abcdefgh` and I get this screen:

[image]

This is what I want, where the user can select the repositories my GitHub app has access to. But going through the regular GitHub app flow, I get the installation dialog below instead. Why does this dialog look so different? On top, the wording "Acts on your behalf" is poorly choosen. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

[image]

Addendum: I found [this entry](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/using-github-apps/installing-a-github-app-from-a-third-party#difference-between-installation-and-authorization) in the documentation which states:

> You can install a GitHub App without authorizing the app. Similarly, you can authorize the app without installing the app.

So I guess my question is what is the difference between a GitHub app authorization and installation?